# pthreads conditional - it is possible to ignore cond signals?

Tags: pthreads

I'm working with a producer-consumer example in pthreads. The idea is the following. The producer generates a new value `k` which is shared among all the consumer threads. There are `n_consumers` threads and only one producer. In order to ease access to `k`, an array with `n_consumers` elements is employed. This way, everytime a new `k` is generated, it is replicated into the whole `pool` (`pool[0]=k; pool[1]=k;...; pool[n_consumers-1]=k`).

This is a snippet of my code:

```
void *consumer (void *args) {

    int id = *(int *) args;

    while (1) {

        barrier (&barrier1, id);

        // 1. lock
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mu);

        // 2. wait
        pthread_cond_wait (&cond_producer_is_ready, &mu);

        // 3. unlock
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mu);

        // 4. do something with pool[id] value
        printf ("thread %d using value %d\n", id, pool[id]);

        // 5. stop?
        if (stop_condition(pool[id]))
            break;
    }    
    return NULL;
}

void *producer (void *args) {

    int i;
    int id = n_consumers;

    while (1) {

        barrier(&barrier1, id);

        // 1. lock
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mu);    

        // 2. produce some new values
        for (i=0; i<n_consumers; i++)
            pool[i]++;

        // 3. send message indicating a new value is available
        printf ("producer sends broadcast...\n");
        pthread_cond_broadcast (&cond_producer_is_ready); 

        // 4. unlock
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mu);  

        // 5. stop?
        // it could be pool[x], it does not matter the index
        if (stop_condition(pool[0]))
            break;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This is the output:

```
thread 0 in barrier (count 1)
thread 2 in barrier (count 2)
thread 1 in barrier (count 3)
thread 3 in barrier (count 4)
thread 4 in barrier (count 5)  <- all the threads are in the barrier (OK)
producer sends broadcast...  <- producer send the message to access to k
thread 4 in barrier (count 1)  <- the producer waits in the barrier
thread 1 using value 1         <- consumer 1 received the message and use k=1
thread 1 in barrier (count 2)
thread 3 using value 1         <- consumer 2 and 3 received the message too
thread 3 in barrier (count 3)
thread 2 using value 1
thread 2 in barrier (count 4)  <- only the consumer 0 did not received the message
```

It seems that only a few consumers receive the signal `cond_producer_is_ready`, in this case, the consumer threads 1, 2, and 3, whereas the consumer thread 0 is still waiting for such a message. The barrier is working fine because all the threads can reach it. However, the problem is the reception of messages. Is is possible to determine wheter a given sent message (such as `cond_producer_is_ready`) has been received or ignored for a given thread?

**update**
Thanks to @caf for his answer. This is a corrected version of my original code without the previous error, just for completeness (or copy it from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vjjBRhgR)):

```
/*
| barrier_and_pool.c
| $ gcc barrier_and_pool.c -pthread -o barrier_and_pool.out
* */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// shared resource
int *pool                               = NULL;       

// producer and consumers
int n_consumers                         = 4;
int numproc                             = 5;    // n_consumers + 1 producer
int new_value_available                 = 0;    // mutex flag
int last_value_produced                 = 0;    // mutex flag

pthread_mutex_t mu                      = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  
pthread_cond_t  cond_producer_is_ready  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

typedef struct
{
    int             cur_count;
    pthread_mutex_t barrier_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t barrier_cond;
}               barrier_t;

barrier_t pbarrier;

void barrier_init(barrier_t * mybarrier)
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&(mybarrier->barrier_mutex), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(mybarrier->barrier_cond), NULL);
    mybarrier->cur_count = 0;
}


void barrier(barrier_t * mybarrier, int id) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(mybarrier->barrier_mutex));
    mybarrier->cur_count++;
    printf("thread %d in barrier (count %d)\n", id, mybarrier->cur_count);
    if (mybarrier->cur_count!=numproc) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&(mybarrier->barrier_cond), &(mybarrier->barrier_mutex));
    }
    else
    {
        mybarrier->cur_count=0;
        printf ("broadcast sent by thread %d\n", id);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&(mybarrier->barrier_cond));
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mybarrier->barrier_mutex));

    printf ("thread %d out of barrier\n", id);
}

int stop_condition (int k_value) {
    if (k_value >= 5)       // we stop after five iters
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void *consumer (void *args) {

    int id = *(int *) args;
    int last_value_consumed = 0;

    while (1) {

        barrier (&pbarrier, id);

        // 1. lock
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mu);

        // 2. wait
        while (last_value_produced == last_value_consumed)
            pthread_cond_wait (&cond_producer_is_ready, &mu);

        last_value_consumed++;

        // 3. unlock
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mu);

        // 4. do something with pool[id] value
        printf ("thread %d using value %d\n", id, pool[id]);

        // 5. stop?
        if (stop_condition(pool[id]))
            break;
    }    
    return NULL;
}

void *producer (void *args) {

    int i;
    int id = n_consumers;

    while (1) {

        barrier(&pbarrier, id);

        // 1. lock
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mu);    

        // 2. produce some new values
        for (i=0; i<n_consumers; i++)
            pool[i]++;

        // 3. send message indicating a new value is available
        last_value_produced++;
        printf ("producer sends broadcast (last_value_produced: %d)...\n", last_value_produced);
        pthread_cond_broadcast (&cond_producer_is_ready); 

        // 4. unlock
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mu);  

        // 5. stop?
        // it could be pool[x], it does not matter the index
        if (stop_condition(pool[0]))
            break;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {


    pool = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*n_consumers);

    int *ids  = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n_consumers);

    pthread_t pro;
    pthread_t cons[n_consumers];

    // init barrier
    barrier_init(&pbarrier);

    // init consumers
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n_consumers; i++) {
        ids[i] = i;
        pool[i] = 0;
        pthread_create (&cons[i], NULL, consumer, &ids[i]);
    }

    // init producer
    pthread_create (&pro, NULL, producer, NULL);

    // join
    for (i=0; i<n_consumers; i++) {
        pthread_join (cons[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_join (pro, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the producer can acquire the mutex before any or all of the consumers, in which case the consumer(s) will be waiting at the `pthread_mutex_lock();` when the condition is signalled - so they will then wait forever at the `pthread_cond_wait()` (signals aren't queued: if you aren't waiting when the condition variable gets signalled, you'll miss it).

This is why pthread condition variable must be paired with a condition over some shared state - called a *predicate*.  Instead of just calling `pthread_cond_wait()`, you call it in a loop that tests the predicate:

```
while (!new_value_available)
    pthread_cond_wait (&cond_producer_is_ready, &mu);
```

This way it doesn't matter if the producer gets there first or the consumer: if the consumer reaches its critical section before the producer, the predicate will be false and the consumer will wait; if the producer reaches its critical section before the consumer, the condition will be true and the consumer will continue.

In this case, to create your predicate you could have a global shared variable `last_value_produced` initialised to zero and incremented by the producer just before it broadcasts the condition variable.  Each consumer maintains a local variable `last_value_consumed` also initialised to zero, and the condition becomes:

```
while (last_value_consumed == last_value_produced)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond_producer_is_ready, &mu);
```

The consumer then increments `last_value_consumed`.